# how to find kth smallest element in unsorted array using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to learn how correctly find the kth value in an unsorted array using multithreading. I divided the array into subarrays and found the kth value in each. But sometimes, these values don't match the true answer. So, I need to sort each subarray and, after it sorts these subarrays generally, or here is another algorithm for finding the kth value in an unsorted array using multithreading?
My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SearchingItemThread implements Runnable{
    private int[] arr;
    private int left;
    private int right;
    private int k;
    private int median;

    public SearchingItemThread(int[] arr, int left, int right, int k){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       median = select(0, arr.length - 1, k);
    }

    private int select(int left, int right, int k) {
        if (left == right) {
            return arr[left];
        }
        int pivotIndex = partition(left, right);
        if (k == pivotIndex) {
            return arr[k];
        } else if (k < pivotIndex) {
            return select(left, pivotIndex - 1, k);
        } else {
            return select(pivotIndex + 1, right, k);
        }
    }

    private int partition(int left, int right) {
        int pivotIndex = getPivot(left, right);
        int pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];
        swap(pivotIndex, right);
        int storeIndex = left;
        for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < pivotValue) {
                swap(i, storeIndex);
                storeIndex++;
            }
        }
        swap(storeIndex, right);
        return storeIndex;
    }

    private int getPivot(int left, int right) {
        return new Random().nextInt(right - left + 1) + left;
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    public int getMedian() {
        return median;
    }
}


 public int findResultByMultithreading(int numberOfThreads, List<Integer> list, int target){

        int[][] subArrays = new int[numberOfThreads][];
        int subarraySize = list.size() / numberOfThreads;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            int startIndex = i * subarraySize;
            int endIndex = (i == numberOfThreads - 1) ? list.size() : (i + 1) * subarraySize;
            subArrays[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray(), startIndex, endIndex);
        }

        Thread[] searcher = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
        SearchingItemThread[] runnables = new SearchingItemThread[numberOfThreads];
        List<Integer> medians = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfThreads - 1; i++) {
            runnables[i] = new SearchingItemThread(subArrays[i], 0, subArrays[i].length - 1, target);
            searcher[i] = new Thread(runnables[i]);

            searcher[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            try {
                searcher[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            medians.add(runnables[i].getMedian());
        }
        
        System.out.println(medians);
}
```

For example, I have an array: [4, 7, 2, 9, 5, 1, 6, 8, 3] and k = 3. If I divide this array into three group I get [4, 7, 2], [9, 5, 1] and [6, 8, 3]. In each subarray the third element is [7, 9, 8]. These values dont` match the true answer - 3

Comment: For example, I have an array: [4, 7, 2, 9, 5, 1, 6, 8, 3] and k = 3. If I divide this array into three group I get [4, 7, 2], [9, 5, 1] and [6, 8, 3]. In each subarray the third element is [7, 9, 8]. These values dont` match the true answer - 3.

Answer (score 0):

You're using parallel Quickselects to find the *k*<sup>th</sup>-least element in each subarray.  As you observe, it is not necessarily the case that any of these is the *k*<sup>th</sup>-least overall.  But those Quickselects are doing more for you than finding the exact *k*<sup>th</sup>-least element of each subarray.  They are rearranging the arrays so that **all** the *k* least elements of each subarray are on one end.  Somewhere among those *nk* elements is the overall *k*<sup>th</sup> least.

There are several ways you could proceed.  For example,

1. You could sort the *k* least elements of each subarray (in parallel), and then use an approach akin to an *n*-way merge to find the overall least (less or no parallelization for this part).  OR
2. You could use a heap / priority queue in a couple of different ways to find the target number, such as

   - add all the *nk* least elements to a min-heap, then make *k* selections, OR
   - form *k* elements into a max-heap, then check each of the other (*n*-1)*k* elements: if an element E it is less than the max, then remove the max and insert E into the heap.  After all elements have been considered, the maximum remaining in the heap is the target element.
   - form each of the sub-arrays' groups of least elements into a min-heap, and make *k* selections overall, each time the least from any of the heaps.

   These heap-based parts probably need to be all-serial.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the k'th smallest element using k threads each having a partition of the array.

Find the minimum of each partition. The greatest of the minimum values is the initial value for the result. Now this thread is no longer needed. The other threads proceed with searching for the second-smallest item in their partitions and compare it with our current candidate. Whichever has it's second-smallest item greater than the current candidate can stop its work. If there were some threads whose second-smallest item was smaller than the current candidate can continue the search.

This modus operandi is to be repeated until there are no more thread to continue the search and the candidate that remains standing is the response to the question.